# How to use importXML function with a file from Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have an .xml file stored in Drive and would like to extract information using importXML(). However, it doesn't work when it's a sharable link is from Drive.

Comment: I think it's not possible because google drive sharable link doesn't expose XML as a direct link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that there are 2 patterns.

### 1. Read directly XML files from Google Drive

In this case, all XML files which are used on Spreadsheet have to be shared as ANYONE_WITH_LINK and VIEW. The URL of the shared file is `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=### file id ###&export=download`. So the formula is as follows.

```
=importXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=### file id ###&export=download","### XPath query ###")
```

### 2. Read indirectly XML files using Web Apps

In this case, the XML files which are used on Spreadsheet are not required to share, because Web Apps is deployed. But GAS is used for this case. The install of this method is as follows.

#### 1. Copy and paste following script on your script editor.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var xml = DriveApp.getFileById(e.parameters.id).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(xml).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
}
```

#### 2. [Deploy Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

- On the Script Editor

  - File
  - -> Manage Versions
  - -> Save New Version
  - Publish
  - -> Deploy as Web App
  - -> At Execute the app as, select **"your account"**
  - -> At Who has access to the app, select **"Anyone, even anonymous"**
  - -> Click "Deploy"
  - -> Copy **"Current web app URL"**
  - -> Click "OK"

The copied **Current web app URL** is used for `importXML()`. So the formula on Spreadsheet is as follows.

```
=importXML("https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec?id=### file id ###","### XPath query ###")
```

If these were not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Option 1 worked great for me and was the simplest for my use case!

Comment: @Jon Horton I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too!

Comment: Unfortunately in 2020 non of these work anymore. When selecting the root of the reply (xpath "/") I can see the reason, why: 
Option 1: "Meet Google Drive – One place for all your files..." and the rest of the HTML of the Google Drive landing page. This is very strange as pasting the same URL into a web browser downloads the XML file...
Option 2: "Sign in - Google Accounts..." and the rest of Google sign in page HTML. I have played with various GAS deploy options, but it's the same.
Seems that I have to upload my XML into an AWS S3 bucket to be able to import them into Google Sheets :-)

Comment: @throbi Thank you for your comment. From your comment, when I tested above both patterns now, I could confirm that both patterns worked fine. But I think that your proposal will be also useful.

Comment: Its 2022 and the first solution worked for me with some twists:
1. I had to change the access to the Drive folder to "Anyone with link" and "view" - without this, the result will keep asking you to sign in.
2. I changed the file URL to "https://https://drive.google.com/file/d/### file id ###/view?export=download"

Comment: I kept getting blocked by "Google Drive can't scan this file for viruses. / This file is executable and may harm your computer.", renaming the file to `.txt` got around that (suggested here: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/225590312/importing-xml-from-drive-into-google-sheet?hl=en). `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###file_id###/view?export=download` did not work, `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=###file_id###&export=download` did.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sharing as "anyone with link"and "view" I had to use:

[https://drive.google.com/uc?id={FILE_ID}&export=download&confirm=t](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=%7BFILE_ID%7D&export=download&confirm=t)

Example:
from file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0lasqWgGnpaAFsoxIzSEb52qFx4-ROr/view?usp=sharing

file id: 1w0lasqWgGnpaAFsoxIzSEb52qFx4-ROr

Resulting url: [https://drive.google.com/uc?id={FILE_ID}&export=download&confirm=t](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=%7BFILE_ID%7D&export=download&confirm=t)

=IMPORTXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1w0lasqWgGnpaAFsoxIzSEb52qFx4-ROr&export=download&confirm=t";"/*")