# Google ImportXML from QGIS metadata file

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, qgis

I am trying to capture elements of an qmd file (that is xml markup) using Google Sheets importxml. Based on [How to use importXML function with a file from Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988417/how-to-use-importxml-function-with-a-file-from-google-drive?rq=1) I think I've got the file importing correctly but can't seem to capture any of the tags.

Here's what I am trying -

```
=importXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AI2C8hQnSOuuoyJXizYBszGmpMXW8xxT&export=download","\\identifier")
```

Here's what the qmd/xml file looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis version="3.9.0-Master">
  <identifier>Z:/My Drive/Mangoesmapping/Spatial Projects/2019/DSC/132_Ongoing_Asset_Updates/Working/Sewerage_Updates/Sewerage_Manholes_InspectionShafts.TAB</identifier>
  <parentidentifier>Sewerage Manhole Infrastructure</parentidentifier>
  <language>AUS</language>
  <type>dataset</type>
  <title>Sewerage Manholes within Douglas Shire Council</title>
  <abstract>Sewerage Manholes within Douglas Shire Council. Most data has been updated based on field work, review of existing AsCon files and discussion with council staff responsible for the assets in 2018/2019. In Port Douglas most of the infrastructure has been surveyed in. </abstract>
  <keywords vocabulary="gmd:topicCategory">
    <keyword>Infrastructure</keyword>
    <keyword>Sewerage</keyword>
```

If I use

```
=importXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AI2C8hQnSOuuoyJXizYBszGmpMXW8xxT&export=download","*")
```

I get
[image]

But I really would like to just get the elements I want by placing the importxml for each tag in the cell I need it in.

Comment: I thought that your file of `1hZG7q9QaNB637oq-BNdID0Gn_-kcoAVb` might be different from the XML data in your question. Because in your file of `1hZG7q9QaNB637oq-BNdID0Gn_-kcoAVb`, `fileIdentifier` cannot be found. Can you confirm about this?

Comment: I've been working on it since then - the google sheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jgTL7G1CqIveZnBtS_ntJJ1-dQ33juixjnQDqGXl7S8/edit?usp=sharing  (see the worksheets called XML_*), the xml as qmd file is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AI2C8hQnSOuuoyJXizYBszGmpMXW8xxT/view - you are right though that somewhere in the process the fileIndentifier has dropped but even a tag there now doesn't work - for example =importXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AI2C8hQnSOuuoyJXizYBszGmpMXW8xxT&export=download","\\identifier")

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. I think that ``\\`` of `\\identifier` is `//`. So how about this? `=importXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AI2C8hQnSOuuoyJXizYBszGmpMXW8xxT&export=download","//identifier")`

Comment: Oh so simple -thank you. It works. If you post an answer can you tell me why this is the case?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I posted it as an answer by including the explanation. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve `###` of `<identifier>###</identifier>` from `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AI2C8hQnSOuuoyJXizYBszGmpMXW8xxT&export=download`

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Issue:

In your question, the formula of `=importXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AI2C8hQnSOuuoyJXizYBszGmpMXW8xxT&export=download","\\identifier")` uses `\\identifier` as the xpath. From your data you want to retrieve the values, it seems that you are trying to retrieve `###` of `<identifier>###</identifier>`.

In this case, in order to `Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are`, `//` is required to be used instead of `\\`. This can be seen at the document of [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

#### Modified formula:

So `=importXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AI2C8hQnSOuuoyJXizYBszGmpMXW8xxT&export=download","\\identifier")` can be modified as follows.

```
=importXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AI2C8hQnSOuuoyJXizYBszGmpMXW8xxT&export=download","//identifier")
```

As other xpath, from your data in your question, you can also use the xpath of `/qgis/identifier` instead of `//identifier`. So you can also use the following formula.

```
=importXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AI2C8hQnSOuuoyJXizYBszGmpMXW8xxT&export=download","/qgis/identifier")
```

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: that's great. One quick question if there's xml like the following how can I get the spatial_minx value for example?    <extent>
    <spatial minx="322783.17999999999301508" minz="0" crs="EPSG:28355" maxx="337384.35999999998603016" miny="8170597.66000000014901161" maxz="0" dimensions="2" maxy="8181833.33999999985098839"/>
    <temporal>

Comment: @GeorgeC Thank you for replying. About your new issue, unfortunately, I couldn't propose the complete answer from the information in your replying because I'm not sure about whole data. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to confirm it and think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: -OK I have posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211172/extract-sub-category-info-from-xml-using-google-sheets-import-xml