# Import XML content from a cell – Google spreadsheets

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem I can't solve myself :(
I have a spreadsheet it's A1 content is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tsResponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableau.com/api http://tableau.com/api/ts-api-3.11.xsd">
    <pagination pageNumber="1" pageSize="100" totalAvailable="1"/>
    <views>
        <view id="96006974-18a1-4f65-8372-702fb964d36a" name="Obesity" contentUrl="Regional/sheets/Obesity" createdAt="2021-04-09T13:41:13Z" updatedAt="2021-04-09T13:41:13Z" viewUrlName="Obesity">
            <workbook id="1b66b892-fb08-4639-9d97-8561a3d63f9b"/>
            <owner id="528e5efa-e928-4341-bd59-8c0790227c67"/>
            <project id="ca5b55fa-9094-4543-a92c-64608028143f"/>
            <tags/>
        </view>
    </views>
</tsResponse>
```

I need to parse it and get an id of `/view`

So I managed to get all id by uploading the file and using it from https://earthy-cows.surge.sh/tableau_response.xml, but:

1. I can't manage to do IMPORTXML content from A1 cell value. Is it possible? Can't find any info
2. How to change do get id only from /view? To get all Id's I use `=IMPORTXML("https://earthy-cows.surge.sh/tableau_response.xml","//@id")` but `//view/@id"` as Xpath doesn't work. Also it doesn't work again with importing from a cell (see question #1)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Answer for Question 1:

> I can't manage to do IMPORTXML content from A1 cell value. Is it possible? Can't find any info

### Workaround 1:

`IMPORTXML` retrieves the XML data from outside. So for example, when Web Apps is used, the values can be retrieved using `IMPORTXML` and xpath. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45988417) For your situation, the sample script is as follows.

#### 1. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet.

```
const doGet = e => ContentService.createTextOutput(e.parameter.data).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps.

The detail information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.

   - This is the important of this workaround.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.

   - In this case, the user is not required to use the access token. So please use this as a test case. In your situation, I thought that this setting is suitable.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. Copy the URL of Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
   - You can see the detail of this at the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### 3. Testing.

As the test of this Web Apps, please put the following formula to a cell. In this case, please replace `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec` with your URL. And, the cell "A1" has your XML data. The xpath is from the following "Answer for Question 2".

```
=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?data=",A1),"//*[local-name()='view']//*/@id")
```

[image]

### Workaround 2:

When the Web Apps is used in your situation, the XML data is retrieved from a cell. In this case, there is the limitation that "URL Fetch URL length" is 2 kbytes. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) I'm worry about this limitation for your actual situation. From this situation, as another workaround for achieving your goal, I would like to propose to use the custom function created by Google Apps Script. When the custom function is used, the values can be retrieved using XmlService. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and save it.

```
function SAMPLE(xml) {
  const root = XmlService.parse(xml).getRootElement();
  const ns = root.getNamespace();
  return root.getChild("views", ns).getChild("view", ns).getChildren().reduce((ar, e) => {
    const id = e.getAttribute("id");
    if (id) ar.push(id.getValue());
    return ar;
  }, []);
}
```

- When you use this script, please put the custom formula of `=SAMPLE(A1)` to a cell.
- In this workaround, when you want to retrieve other values, please modify the script.

#### Result:

When above script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

## Answer for Question 2:

> How to change do get id only from /view? To get all Id's I use =IMPORTXML("https://earthy-cows.surge.sh/tableau_response.xml","//@id") but //view/@id" as Xpath doesn't work. Also it doesn't work again with importing from a cell (see question #1)

In this case, how about modifying the xpath to `//*[local-name()='view']//*/@id`? When your formula is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://earthy-cows.surge.sh/tableau_response.xml","//*[local-name()='view']//*/@id")
```

#### Result:

When above formula is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

## References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)