# Google Sheets IMPORTXML from xml file in google drive shows Virus Scan Warning

Tags: xml, import, google-sheets-formula, virus, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to import information from a .xml file stored in my google drive, to a google sheets. When using the importxml() function, the url is recognized, but it gets to the warning message.

I proceeded as follows, based on what I saw in other posts:

1. I uploaded the xml file to my Google Drive, and obtained the FILE ID from the share link.
2. The share file options were set to "Anyone with the link" and permission to "Viewer".
3. In a Google Sheets, I placed the URL with the following structure in cell A1:

`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=  FILE ID   &export=download`

4. I have the importxml() function in another cell. To display everything in the xml file, I used the "/" xpath as the second argument:

`=importxml(A1; "/")`

However, instead of getting to the xml file, the output is the virus scan warning message from Google Drive (it is pretty long, I only copied the first couple of lines):

```
Google Drive - Virus scan warning#gb{font:13px/27px 
Arial,sans-serif;height:30px}#gbz,#gbg{position:absolute;white-space:nowrap;top:0;height:30px;z-index:1000}#gbz{left:0;padding-
...
```

I tested changing the share settings, different .xml files, and different xpaths, however, I keep getting the same result. Is there a way that I can skip the virus scan and get to the xml, or do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: In your situation, is this method useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67054235/7108653 By the way, how much file size is your XML file?

Comment: Thanks, @Tanaike, I didn't do it as in the post you referenced, but it actually helped me to do it via Apps Script. I ended up extracting the text from the link and using regex to extract information. I known it is not the most robust method for xml, but it works for me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users.